# Why is the web scraped HTML not matching the HTML in the developer tool Elements Panel

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to use the **bs4** (Beautiful Soup 4) and **requests** libraries in python to scrape key data from websites for a work based project that I've been assigned. Although I've mainly got my web scraping program to work, I'm running into issues on certain websites such as Google.

The problem is the HTML that is being scraped by my program on certain websites is not matching the HTML as is being displayed in the developer tool Elements Panel on a lot of browsers.

Consider the following "visual testing" extract from my program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_source = r'https://google.com/search?q=stack+overflow'
response_object = requests.get(URL_source).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response_object, 'lxml')

soup = str(soup.prettify())
soup = soup.split('\n')

for i in range(20):
    print(soup[i])
```

This program is supposed to scrape and print out the first 20 lines of the HTML underpinning the Google page that results from searching "stack overflow" in Google (https://google.com/search?q=stack+overflow). The output that I get using the Spyder IDE is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
 <head>
  <style nonce="RJFpNnOeRBbdIaYpv+jsHw">
   a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
  color: #1a73e8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 24px auto 5px auto;
```

However, this HTML code appears to be very different from what Chrome's (and Microsoft Edge's) developer tool Elements Panel (keyboard shortcut: F12) suggests is the underlying HTML code:
[Results from Chrome's developer tool Elements Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGrb.png)

**Why is this discrepancy arising?**

For reference, please find attached all 522 lines of the HTML code returned by the Beautifulsoup object in the code above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
 <head>
  <style nonce="R4oHWJEKxiyGYDK3s9bn1A">
   a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
  color: #1a73e8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 24px auto 5px auto;
  max-width: 520px;
  padding: 24px;
}
h1 {
  color: #2c2c2c;
  font-size: 24px;
  hyphens: auto;
  margin: 24px 0;
}
p, .sub, .contentText {
  color: #5f6368;;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  text-align: left;
}
.signin {
  text-align: right;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  margin: 14px auto;
}
.basebutton {
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}
a.button {
  color: #fff;
}
button, .button {
  background-color: #1a73e8;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
input.button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.error {
  border: 2px solid #d93025;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #d93025;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
.footer {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.footer a {
  margin-left: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.footer a, .footer select, .footer input {
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.languagepicker {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
#languageform,
#languageselect {
  margin: 0 2px;
}
#languageselect {
  color: #757575;
}
.detailspage {
  margin: 24px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.detailspage h1, .detailspage h2 {
  font-size: 22px
}
.setting {
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  padding: 24px 24px 20px 24px;
  text-align: right;
}
.sub {
  padding: 24px 24px 20px 24px;
}
hr {
  margin: 12px -24px 12px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dadce0;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
label {
  margin: 24px;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.setting h2, .setting h3, h4 {
  color: #3c4043;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.yt-text {
  color: #5f6368;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.productLogoContainer {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 360px;
}

/** Narrow screen (for example a mobile device). */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    margin: 18px 14px;
  }
  .imgContainer {
    min-width: 96px;
  }
  .hideOnSmallWidth {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer form {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .imgContainer {
    min-width: 72px;
  }
}

/** Normal/non-narrow screen. */
@media not screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    margin: 18px 25px;
  }
  .imgContainer {
    width: 51%;
  }
  .hideOnNormalWidth {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer form {
    display: inline;
  }
}
  </style>
  <title>
   Before you continue to Google Search
  </title>
  <meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, width=device-width" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="//www.google.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="signin">
   <a class="basebutton button" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&amp;continue=https://www.google.com/search?q%3Dstack%2Boverflow&amp;gae=cb-">
    Sign in
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <img alt="Google" height="28" src="//www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_68x28dp.png" srcset="//www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_68x28dp.png 2x" width="68"/>
   <div class="productLogoContainer">
    <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" class="image" height="100%" src="https://www.gstatic.com/ac/cb/scene_cookie_wall_search_v2.svg" width="100%"/>
   </div>
   <h1>
    Before you continue to Google Search
   </h1>
   <div class="contentText">
    Google uses
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/technologies/cookies?hl=en&amp;utm_source=ucb" target="_blank">
     cookies
    </a>
    and data to:
    <ul>
     <li>
      Deliver and maintain services, like tracking outages and protecting against spam, fraud, and abuse
     </li>
     <li>
      Measure audience engagement and site statistics to understand how our services are used
     </li>
    </ul>
    If you agree, we’ll also use cookies and data to:
    <ul>
     <li>
      Improve the quality of our services and develop new ones
     </li>
     <li>
      Deliver and measure the effectiveness of ads
     </li>
     <li>
      Show personalized content, depending on your settings
     </li>
     <li>
      Show personalized or generic ads, depending on your settings, on Google and across the web
     </li>
    </ul>
    For non-personalized content and ads, what you see may be influenced by things like the content you’re currently viewing and your location (ad serving is based on general location). Personalized content and ads can be based on those things and your activity like Google searches and videos you watch on YouTube. Personalized content and ads include things like more relevant results and recommendations, a customized YouTube homepage, and ads that are tailored to your interests.
    <p>
     Click “Customize” to review options, including controls to reject the use of cookies for personalization and information about browser-level controls to reject some or all cookies for other uses. You can also visit g.co/privacytools anytime.
    </p>
   </div>
   <div>
    <a class="basebutton button" href="https://consent.google.com/dl?continue=https://www.google.com/search?q%3Dstack%2Boverflow&amp;gl=GB&amp;hl=en&amp;pc=srp&amp;src=1">
     Customize
    </a>
    <form action="https://consent.google.com/s" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
     <input name="gl" type="hidden" value="GB"/>
     <input name="m" type="hidden" value="0"/>
     <input name="pc" type="hidden" value="srp"/>
     <input name="continue" type="hidden" value="https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow"/>
     <input name="ca" type="hidden" value="r"/>
     <input name="x" type="hidden" value="8"/>
     <input name="v" type="hidden" value="cb.20211212-16-p1.en+FX+989"/>
     <input name="t" type="hidden" value="ADw3F8gQY3JFW6CvULVIi1GWLM3juX0i1w:1640013243360"/>
     <input name="hl" type="hidden" value="en"/>
     <input name="src" type="hidden" value="1"/>
     <input aria-label="Agree to the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described" class="basebutton button" type="submit" value="I agree"/>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <form action="https://consent.google.com/ml" method="get">
    <select id="languageselect" name="hl">
     <option value="af">
      Afrikaans
     </option>
     <option value="az">
      azərbaycan
     </option>
     <option value="bs">
      bosanski
     </option>
     <option value="ca">
      català
     </option>
     <option value="cs">
      Čeština
     </option>
     <option value="cy">
      Cymraeg
     </option>
     <option value="da">
      Dansk
     </option>
     <option value="de">
      Deutsch
     </option>
     <option value="et">
      eesti
     </option>
     <option value="en-GB">
      English (United Kingdom)
     </option>
     <option selected="" value="en">
      English (United States)
     </option>
     <option value="es">
      Español (España)
     </option>
     <option value="es-419">
      Español (Latinoamérica)
     </option>
     <option value="eu">
      euskara
     </option>
     <option value="fil">
      Filipino
     </option>
     <option value="fr-CA">
      Français (Canada)
     </option>
     <option value="fr">
      Français (France)
     </option>
     <option value="ga">
      Gaeilge
     </option>
     <option value="gl">
      galego
     </option>
     <option value="hr">
      Hrvatski
     </option>
     <option value="id">
      Indonesia
     </option>
     <option value="zu">
      isiZulu
     </option>
     <option value="is">
      íslenska
     </option>
     <option value="it">
      Italiano
     </option>
     <option value="sw">
      Kiswahili
     </option>
     <option value="lv">
      latviešu
     </option>
     <option value="lt">
      lietuvių
     </option>
     <option value="hu">
      magyar
     </option>
     <option value="ms">
      Melayu
     </option>
     <option value="nl">
      Nederlands
     </option>
     <option value="no">
      norsk
     </option>
     <option value="uz">
      o‘zbek
     </option>
     <option value="pl">
      polski
     </option>
     <option value="pt-BR">
      Português (Brasil)
     </option>
     <option value="pt-PT">
      Português (Portugal)
     </option>
     <option value="ro">
      română
     </option>
     <option value="sq">
      shqip
     </option>
     <option value="sk">
      Slovenčina
     </option>
     <option value="sl">
      slovenščina
     </option>
     <option value="sr-Latn">
      srpski (latinica)
     </option>
     <option value="fi">
      Suomi
     </option>
     <option value="sv">
      Svenska
     </option>
     <option value="vi">
      Tiếng Việt
     </option>
     <option value="tr">
      Türkçe
     </option>
     <option value="el">
      Ελληνικά
     </option>
     <option value="be">
      беларуская
     </option>
     <option value="bg">
      български
     </option>
     <option value="ky">
      кыргызча
     </option>
     <option value="kk">
      қазақ тілі
     </option>
     <option value="mk">
      македонски
     </option>
     <option value="mn">
      монгол
     </option>
     <option value="ru">
      Русский
     </option>
     <option value="sr">
      српски
     </option>
     <option value="uk">
      Українська
     </option>
     <option value="ka">
      ქართული
     </option>
     <option value="hy">
      հայերեն
     </option>
     <option value="iw">
      עברית
     </option>
     <option value="ur">
      اردو
     </option>
     <option value="ar">
      العربية
     </option>
     <option value="fa">
      فارسی
     </option>
     <option value="am">
      አማርኛ
     </option>
     <option value="ne">
      नेपाली
     </option>
     <option value="mr">
      मराठी
     </option>
     <option value="hi">
      हिन्दी
     </option>
     <option value="as">
      অসমীয়া
     </option>
     <option value="bn">
      বাংলা
     </option>
     <option value="pa">
      ਪੰਜਾਬੀ
     </option>
     <option value="gu">
      ગુજરાતી
     </option>
     <option value="or">
      ଓଡ଼ିଆ
     </option>
     <option value="ta">
      தமிழ்
     </option>
     <option value="te">
      తెలుగు
     </option>
     <option value="kn">
      ಕನ್ನಡ
     </option>
     <option value="ml">
      മലയാളം
     </option>
     <option value="si">
      සිංහල
     </option>
     <option value="th">
      ไทย
     </option>
     <option value="lo">
      ລາວ
     </option>
     <option value="my">
      မြန်မာ
     </option>
     <option value="km">
      ខ្មែរ
     </option>
     <option value="ko">
      한국어
     </option>
     <option value="ja">
      日本語
     </option>
     <option value="zh-CN">
      简体中文
     </option>
     <option value="zh-TW">
      繁體中文
     </option>
     <option value="zh-HK">
      繁體中文 (香港)
     </option>
    </select>
    <input name="oldhl" type="hidden" value="en"/>
    <input name="gl" type="hidden" value="GB"/>
    <input name="m" type="hidden" value="0"/>
    <input name="pc" type="hidden" value="srp"/>
    <input name="continue" type="hidden" value="https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow"/>
    <input name="src" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Change language"/>
   </form>
   <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en&amp;utm_source=ucb">
    Privacy Policy
   </a>
   <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en&amp;utm_source=ucb">
    Terms of Service
   </a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated. I'm sure many of you will be able to see the source of the problem straight away. I suspect that the fact that the HTML extract that I've scraped is in a (mostly) json format might hold some clues.

Thank you.

Comment: google may not like that you are accessing their page like this, have you seen the entire returned html document? does it say anything or does it show results? with some websites if you try to access them like this they may return an html that warns you about accessing their site with automated software. Have you tried using headers? I have heard that they sometimes fix something

Comment: Hello Matiiss. Thank you for your reply.

I'm aware that a lot of larger websites tend to place restrictions on an automated program's ability to hit the website (as this can cause the website to crash in some circumstances). However, my initial research into this problem seems to suggest that Google haven't necessarily put this restriction in place.

I have seen the entire returned HTML, and there's no content in it as displayed on the webpage.

Do you have any suggestions :)?

Comment: Does the content on the returned HTML give you any clue as to what could have happened? Or does it just have different search results?

Comment: I've now attached all of the HTML code returned by the Beautifulsoup object in my code above for your reference (as you will see in the body above). There are a number of <input> tags with the attribute type="hidden", which might explain the difficulties I'm having (although I don't know for sure). Furthermore, as you will see if you try to execute the full HTML extract, Google blocks the connection. Do you think there's anything fundamentally wrong with my code, or is it simply the case that Google blocks web scraping of this type?

Comment: Would an API be the only option for automatically pulling data and content from google searches, or is there another web scraping approach I could use with Google?

Comment: your code is asking a very simple request, so my bet is on google blocking or "avoiding" your request and APIs are definitely what you should use especially if the service provides it which google definitely does so I would suggest that you use it (also I think that there is a python library (on PyPI) that pulls searches from google so you can search that up but really you should use the API)

Answer (score 1):

Try using another link as google is a search engine, its source code changes each time we search a query. Try using simple links like https://hacknetayush.repl.co

Comment: Hello HackNewAyush. Thank you for your reply. What link would you suggest as an alternative to the one that I've used in the code that I've provided :)?

Comment: You can use link like: https://hacknetayush.repl.co

Comment: I don't have a problem scraping data from basic websites or links like the one you attached previously :). What I meant was "Could you suggest a Google based link as an alternative to the one that I've used in the code that I've provided". Is there another URL that I could use to scrape the same content and data as is being displayed in the web page (https://google.com/search?q=stack+overflow)? Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** *Developer Tools operate on a live browser DOM, what you’ll see when inspecting the page source is not the original HTML, but a modified one after applying some browser clean up and executing JavaScript code.*

Requests is not executing JavaScript so content can deviate slightly, but you can scrape - Just take a deeper look into your soup.

---

#### How to "fix"?

Come up with some `headers` in your request and try to show *"it is a browser"* that like to get an response (copy your headers from dev tools, so, google won't ask for cookies, ...)

```
headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}

URL_source = r'https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow'
response_object = requests.get(URL_source,headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response_object, 'lxml')

[x.text for x in soup.select('a:has(h3)')]
```

#### Output

```
['Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build ...https://stackoverflow.com',
 'Stack Overflow (@StackOverflow) · Twitterhttps://twitter.com/StackOverflow',
 'Stack Overflow (Website) - Wikipediahttps://de.wikipedia.org › wiki › Stack_Overflow_(Web...',
 'Stack Overflow - Wikipediahttps://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › St...',
 'Softwareentwicklung: So geht es weiter bei Stack Overflowhttps://www.heise.de › news › Softwareentwicklung-So-...',
 'Stack Overflow Blog - Essays, opinions, and advice on the act ...https://stackoverflow.blog']
```

Comment: Hi HedgeHog. Thank you for your reply. I have seen the entire returned HTML, and there's no content in it as displayed on the webpage. I appreciate what you've outlined, that the developer tools do a lot of cleaning and modification to the original HTML, but where is the content (as presented on the webpage and in the cleaned and modified HTML in the developer tools) being extracted from? What parts of the soup should I take a deeper look into :)?

Comment: Could not tell you, what you will see in your soup explicitly, but mostly there are some things mentioned about, you are not a browser or could not handle js or have to accept cookies first, ... - Added an example, that may fix your issue, but es mentioned it is not bulletproofed, cause website try to prevent from bot traffic.

Comment: I've now attached all of the HTML code returned by the Beautifulsoup object in my code above for your reference (as you will see in the body above). There are a number of <input> tags with the attribute type="hidden", which might explain the difficulties I'm having (although I don't know for sure). Furthermore, as you will see if you try to execute the full HTML extract, Google blocks the connection. Do you think there's anything fundamentally wrong with my code, or is it simply the case that Google blocks web scraping of this type (trying to prevent bot traffic)?

Comment: Would an API be the only option for automatically pulling data and content from google searches, or is there another web scraping approach I could use with Google?